# How to stop the music?

Tags: media-player, media, jfxpanel

I dont know how to stop the music here. Can anyone help me how to code.

```
private void mActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
    JFXPanel j = new JFXPanel();
    String uri = new File("src/Tiến_Quân_Ca.mp3").toURI() .toString();
    if(m.isSelected()){
try{

new MediaPlayer(new Media(uri)).play();
}catch (Exception ex){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);  
                     }
    }
}
```

I put this code on jtogglebutton, can you please show me how?